# body background-image is not visible

Tags: html, css, background-image

For some weird reason my body background image doesn't show up. Any one an idea why that might be?
My tag looks like this:

```
body,
body.overlay {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font: 11px/160% Verdana;
  color: #494949;
  background: #75A3D1 url(http://www.transtrata.net/images/bg-body.png) top left repeat-x;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing is your background image url path is right but the image is not available..
I create one fiddle here is the path http://jsfiddle.net/C9YJ9/1/

Answer (score 3):

`http://www.transtrata.net/images/bg-body.png` is 404ing.

Comment: Are you internal to the transtrata.net network? You might have an open firewall path if you work for them or something?